# Why is processing of my batch game always exited on an IF condition?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I try to make a map giving some values, but when I run the command the .bat processing is exited.

This is the snippet of my code:

```
choice /c k >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 goto mchk

:mchk
if %mn%=10 goto playerlevel

:playerlevel
cls
echo test
pause
```

Instead of going to `playerlevel`, the console window gets simply closed.

Comment: TBF, Trash Post, you've not accepted the advice I also provided; your code is not doing what you want it to do. Additionally, I don't see any purpose in using `if %errorlevel%==1 goto mchk` at all, because the end user must have pressed `[K]` in order for the script to continue. If they entered the only other option, `[CTRL]`+`[C]`, the script would not run anyhow! As for checking the `%mn%` value, perhaps `If %mn% Equ 10` could be useful. But without knowing for sure that this can only hold an integer value, I couldn't advise it at this time.

Comment: Read about the comparison operators using the `IF /?` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if %mn%=10 goto playerlevel
```

Should be

```
if %mn%==10 goto playerlevel
```

`=` is not a valid comparison operator, so your code generates a syntax error and aborts processing. When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.